# Excel VBA: How to activate a workbook without its complete name?

Tags: vba, excel

I have multiple excel workbooks open. I want to activate a workbook which has "Final" in its name.

Example: I have three open workbooks called "Workbook1.xlsx", "worKbook2.xlsm" and "workbookFinal.xlsx" open at the same time.

My VBA code is in "Macro.xlsm". Using VBA I want to activate the workbook which has "Final" in it. FYI .. all workbooks are in different paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below, using the `Like` Operator with the wild-card `*`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindFinalWorkbook()

Dim wb As Workbook

' loop through all open workbooks
For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
    If wb.Name Like "*Final*" Then '< -- check if workbook name is Like *Final*
        wb.Activate
        Exit For
    End If
Next wb

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

loop through `Workbooks` collection until finding the right named workbook:

```
Sub wbs()
    Dim wb As Workbook

    For Each wb In Workbooks
        If InStr(wb.Name, "Final") > 0 Then
            wb.Activate
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Though this only works if all Workbooks are opened in the same Excel instance

Comment: LOL, even chose the same `wb` variable :)

Comment: You guys are too kind, I'd have vote close this one! ;) @ShaiRado : `wb` for workbook isn't that surprising! But you were faster than user3598756 who is getting slower! :p

Comment: @R3uK, this time you're wrong! And you're a kind guy too (ref "urgent" cases...)

Comment: @user3598756 : Yup, my bad, you were indeed faster! ;)